# Flutter in VS Code command pallete doesn't find git

Tags: git, flutter, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I've been trying to setup Flutter on my laptop without success. The problem is most likely in the extensions or something in VS Code. I can run flutter commands from Powershell no problem. But the commands executed from the VS Code command palette report this:

```
[flutter] flutter doctor -v
'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH. 
exit code 1
```

Which is weird, I do have git in my computer setup to work directly from Powershell as well - it's in PATH. Also the GIT commands from VS Code available in the command palette work no problem.

Every log I've been able to check reports the above message or just the "where" part.

Please help, if you need any additional information, I'll gladly provide it. Thank you :)

Edit #1:
Flutter doctor generates a crash now. It worked before, but now it's reporting errors. This is the log it generates:

````
```
Flutter crash report; please file at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

## command

flutter doctor

## exception

ArgumentError: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for where.

```
#0      _getExecutable (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:127:5)
#1      LocalProcessManager.runSync (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:94:30)
#2      _WindowsUtils._which (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:239:49)
#3      OperatingSystemUtils.whichAll (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:52:43)
#4      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk.findAndroidHomeDir (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:336:38)
#5      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:360:53)
#6      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:100:41)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:293:23)
#8      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:88:20)
#9      AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:117:32)
#10     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:115:23)
#11     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:115:23)
#12     androidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:19:38)
#13     AndroidWorkflow.canListDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:45:41)
#14     AndroidDevices.canListAnything (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:62:47)
#15     DeviceManager.canListAnything.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:148:80)
#16     Iterable.any (dart:core/iterable.dart:388:15)
#17     DeviceManager.canListAnything (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:148:33)
#18     _DefaultDoctorValidatorsProvider.validators (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:90:25)
#19     Doctor.validators (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:145:46)
#20     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:151:39)
#21     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:252:41)
#22     DoctorCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:59:39)
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:615:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)
#30     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:524:5)
#31     Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:554:7)
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#34     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)
#35     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)
#36     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)
#37     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)
#38     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
#39     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:175:5)
```

## flutter doctor

```
encountered exception: Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for where.

#0      _getExecutable (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:127:5)
#1      LocalProcessManager.runSync (package:process/src/interface/local_process_manager.dart:94:30)
#2      _WindowsUtils._which (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:239:49)
#3      OperatingSystemUtils.whichAll (package:flutter_tools/src/base/os.dart:52:43)
#4      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk.findAndroidHomeDir (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:336:38)
#5      AndroidSdk.locateAndroidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:360:53)
#6      AppContext._generateIfNecessary.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:100:41)
#7      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:293:23)
#8      AppContext._generateIfNecessary (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:88:20)
#9      AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:117:32)
#10     AppContext.get (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:115:23)
#11     androidSdk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_sdk.dart:19:38)
#12     AndroidWorkflow.canListDevices (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:45:41)
#13     AndroidDevices.canListAnything (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:62:47)
#14     DeviceManager.canListAnything.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:148:80)
#15     Iterable.any (dart:core/iterable.dart:388:15)
#16     DeviceManager.canListAnything (package:flutter_tools/src/device.dart:148:33)
#17     _DefaultDoctorValidatorsProvider.validators (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:90:25)
#18     Doctor.validators (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:145:46)
#19     Doctor.startValidatorTasks (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:151:39)
#20     Doctor.diagnose (package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:252:41)
#21     _doctorText.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:205:26)
#22     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
#23     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#24     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#25     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#26     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#27     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
#28     _doctorText (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:204:19)
#29     _createLocalCrashReport (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:182:32)
#30     _handleToolError (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:138:31)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:68:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#32     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#33     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#34     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#35     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1502:12)
#36     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:61:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#37     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:146:29)
#38     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)
#39     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)
#40     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1518:10)
#41     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1465:12)
#42     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:145:18)
#43     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:64:24)
#44     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:50:10)
#45     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:65:9)
#46     main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/k/archive/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8:3)
#47     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
#48     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, what I was missing `C:\Windows\System32` value from my `PATH` variable. I had the Powershell in my PATH but not System32. To get Flutter working you need both.

My advice to anyone having a similar error is, check the default values of the PATH variable and set them back :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I upgraded to flutter 1.19.0-3 and I solved it.
This issue is likely caused by the "path variable", I suggest you make sure that your path contains all of the following routes.
'system32, Git bin, flutter bin and powershell'. If you are using Windows, these routes are usually the following, so you can copy the following lines into your 'path variable'.

```
C:\Windows\System32;
C:\Program Files\Git\bin
C:\flutter\bin;
%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I've commented in my solution. I was for some reason missing the 1st line (in your case). Interesting how an updated messed that up.

Answer (score 0):

Install git desktop on to your computer and restart your IDE.

Comment: I've done as you asked. Still not working. I have git working from any other terminal, except VSCode Flutter tasks.

Comment: Have you checked git path in environment variables ?

Comment: Yes, it is there. I've explicitly set path to git.exe in VSCode as well, but that changed nothing. The PATH has to point to the "bin" directory in Git, correct?

Comment: Yeah you are correct. And you can use android studio or intelj as a IDE

Comment: I have not yet tried it. I will later on today and report back.

Comment: Android studio reports the following problem:
```Flutter device daemon #1: process exited during startup. Exit code: 1, stderr: 'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.```

Comment: run flutter doctor and comment a screenshot in here

Comment: I think you have to reinstall flutter and build the project again

Comment: Reinstall Flutter? There is no installation, only adding it to path and adding plugins to Android Studio + emulators. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I mean download and extract flutter. Use flutter documentation then after run flutter doctor to verify there aren't any errors in your installation after build your application

Comment: I've done that to no avail. I have found the solution though. If you'd like to get the points for this thread write the answer bellow. The problem was System32 was not under my PATH variable. So just answer it bellow for everyone to be able to see if the get to this question and I'll mark it as solved. Thanks for the help anyways mate.